# Writing a javascript generated file using File API

Tags: javascript, file-io

I would like to use the File API in Javascript to be able to store generated content on the client browser's file system. I've looked at the documentation, but found no cross-browser solution (FileSystem API appears to be Chrome only).

With File API: Writer being discontinued, I don't know what options I have. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Seems to be widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)

Comment: Why not use the Web-storage API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution that is simple and appears to solve my problem well. With this, I can generate a file and offer a download like link to the user to save. Here is the example code I use:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="fileContent" type="text" cols=80 rows=30>File Content!</textarea>
<a id="anchor" href="#" download="fileContent.txt">Download Me!</a>
<script src="clientfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var fileContent = document.getElementById("fileContent");
var anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");

anchor.onclick = function () {
    var fileContent_blob = new Blob([fileContent.value], {type: 'text/plain'});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob === undefined) {
        anchor.setAttribute('href', URL.createObjectURL(fileContent_blob));
    }
    else {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(fileContent_blob,  'fileContent.txt'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the FileSystem API is only supported in Chrome at the time of this writing, and it will probably not be implemented in other browsers.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Per MDN, the FileSystem API shouldn't be used in production:

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

At the moment better supported options to store files on the client are:

1. Web Storage API - http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage
2. Cookies
3. IndexedDB - http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb
4. WebSQL database - http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage